# Responsive div with background-image

Tags: css

I'm doing a parallax effect inside a div which I perform by adjusting the background image with the scroll, and I need it to be responsive to different screen sizes.  I'd like the image to scale appropriately based off of 100% width and auto height.  The problem is, since the image is a background image, the div is empty so I have to assign it a height.  When you do that then the responsiveness is limited to whatever the height you set.  How can I solve this so that the height can change freely with whatever height the background image has to be?

It'll make sense when you look at the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/d2620kgk/

HTML:

```
<div id='bg-image'></div>
```

CSS:

```
#bg-image{
    background-image: url('../images/portfolio/stoneybrook-full4.jpg');
    background-size:100% auto;
    width:100%;
    height:500px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: try to remove `height:500px` and add `min-height: 500px`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#bg-image{
background-image: url('http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/71/Grant_DeVolson_Wood_-_American_Gothic.jpg/639px-Grant_DeVolson_Wood_-_American_Gothic.jpg');
    background-size:100%;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: That makes the image disappear bc the height becomes 0px.

Comment: Wait, actually you're right. It works... Now I have to figure out how that differs from my actual code.

Comment: Looks like any other content is disguised.  See the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d2620kgk/2/

Comment: Hi! Since this is supposed to be a background layer, add you content inside the bg-image div. It should then render properly.